# Different permissions between REST API and UI

Tags: rest-api, permissions

I'd like to be able to set different permissions for the same user depending on whether they're accessing/editing a resource in the UI or via the REST API. For example, they'd be able to edit a custom field when via the API but only have read-access in the UI. Is this possible?

I'm considering creating an apex class that can be hit via the REST API and locked down with permissions but it seems a waste considering I just want to perform CRUD actions on some standard resources.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If from UI means salesforce UI then you can set field access on page layout... 
You can go to page layout ... Hover over field and click on settings..
[image]

And then click read only

[image]

Then save the layout.

Comment: Thanks, this should help with most fields. However some of the fields are required and they're not selectable as read-only. Is there any way around this?